# Linq query for ordering by ascending order except for one row

Tags: c#, linq

I am pulling data from a table like the example below:

```
status_id   status_description
1             Unknown
2             Personal
3             Terminated
4             Relocated
6             Other
7             LOP
8             Continuing
```

I want to get the results into a IEnumerable which i am then returning to the front end to display the descriptions in a dropdown.

I want to sort this alphabetically and have the "Other" option always show up in the bottom of the dropdown.

Is there any way to get this in the backend? Currently I have this:

```
 IEnumerable<employee_map> map= await(from emp in db.emp_status_map
 orderby emp.status_description
 select emp).ToListAsync();
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply order on two values, first on whether the description is `Other`, then on the actual description itself:

```
orderby emp.status_description == "Other", emp.status_description
```

Comment: @hatchet I always mix up how booleans are ordered; edited.

Comment: Since I wanted to have "Other" show up at the end, i used "descending" in the above. Worked like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Servy's answer is fine, it works and fullfils your requirements. Another solution slightly different would be to add a field called "DisplayOrder", for example, and set it to 1 for all the rows except for "other", and set it to 2 (or whatever number you want) to "other". Then, you just order by DisplayOrder, Description.

It's highly probably that this solution is gonna be much faster if you define an index on DisplayOrder, Description.

Comment: Of course, if you're displaying the values in a drop down there should be a fairly small number of them.  If you have enough items that you need to index this value, then you probably shouldn't be trying to stuff them all into a dropdown.

Comment: I always want to make all the queries as fast as possible because you may have thousands of these queries and many, many users. Of course caching would help. At the same time, I don't like hardcoding the description in my logic. If someone decides to change the description from "other" to "others" would break your code. Having a column called DisplayOrder gives much more flexibility as you could define, for example, a lower display order for the most recently used items. It gives you more flexibility for new requirements.

Comment: Yup the dropdown is pretty small and my number of users are also limited. So the quick solution works for me!